# I'm having trouble positioning the tooltip at the top right side of a div

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I'm messing around with bootstrap tooltip and i'm facing an issue i can't figure out that it is.

My goal was to create some skill progress bars that have a tooltip with the according percentage at the end of bar

[image: like this]

but right now

[image: this]

is what i got, the tooltip stays at the div's left side. I'm using [Ahmet Gür](https://codepen.io/valencia123/pen/aOopQx) pen at codepen to train and get used to the structure.
At this point, i just copy pasted his code and it still doesn't work, so i don't know what it's wrong.

I thought the problem was the `float: right` in the `.tooltip` and tried `right: 0%` but it just made the tooltip disappear from the viewport.

Any idea how i can outcome this issue or what is the possible problem?

This is what i got:

**HTML**

```
            <div class="container col-12 col-md-6">

            <div class="barWrapper">
                <span class="skill-title">Photoshop</span>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                        <span  class="pop-over" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="65%"> </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> 
            </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.tooltip{
   position:relative;
   float: right;
 }
.tooltip > .tooltip-inner {
   background-color: #eebf3f;
   padding:5px 15px;
   color:rgb(23,44,66);
   font-weight:bold;
   font-size:13px;
 }
.pop-over + .tooltip > .tooltip-arrow {
   border-left: 5px solid transparent;
   border-right: 5px solid transparent;
   border-top: 5px solid #eebf3f;
}

.progress{
   border-radius:0;
   overflow:visible;
}
  .progress-bar{
  background:rgb(23,44,60) !important;
  -webkit-transition: width 1.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 1.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({trigger: 'manual'}).tooltip('show');
});


$(".progress-bar").each(function(){
  each_bar_width = $(this).attr('aria-valuenow');
  $(this).width(each_bar_width + '%');
});
```

Comment: You don't have a .tooltip class, nor a .tooltip-inner. you don't have a .tooltip-arrow either

Comment: please update data-placement to right

Comment: @enxaneta I noticed that, but as i said, i was just looking at that code pen i referred, and i was wondering why that didn't work for me. If you open the code pen link, you can see that, al least there, it seems to work fine. That was basically that was bothering me. Today, i did a skill progress bar by myself and it was just fine, but still wanted to understand the issue with this one.

Comment: @saumil_jariwala Just tried it. The tooltip only goes a few px to the right and a few px to bottom